# Adding a generic parameter to an Action delegate

Tags: c#

I'm adding a new feature to an existing code base and I can see the following line,

```
public class Consumer
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, List<Action<byte[], ulong, int>>> _source = new Dictionary<string, List<Action<byte[], ulong, int>>>();
    public void RegisterSource(string source, Action<byte[], ulong, int> onEvent)
    {
        lock (source)
        {
            List<Action<byte[], ulong, int>> sources;

            if (this._source.TryGetValue(source, out sources))
            {
                sources.Add(onEvent);
            }
            else
            {
                var subscriptionList = new List<Action<byte[], ulong, int>>();
                subscriptionList.Add(onEvent);

                this._source.Add(source, subscriptionList);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There are adding to this dictionary on an event. My requirement is that this `_source` dictionary should also allow adding Actions of different parameters like `Action<byte[], ulong, List<string>>`. I tried declaring the dictionary like below,

```
private readonly Dictionary<string, List<Action<byte[], ulong, object>>> _source = new Dictionary<string, List<Action<byte[], ulong, object>>>();
```

But I'm still facing issues. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: C# is a statically compiled language, which means `_source` must have a defined type at compile time. To make the arguments of `Action<T>` generic, it must be contained within a generic class. Please provide more information on where `_source` is declared and how it is used to understand what options exist.

Comment: @JAlex Added more code.

Comment: Did you want the same `Consumer` class instance to work with multiple source types? Or would having a `Consumer<T>` class with `Consumer<int>` and `Consumer<List<string>>` work.

Comment: Also can you give some descriptive names to the arguments of `Action<T1,T2,T3>` especially for `T3` which is the type in question here.

Comment: @JAlex I did try changing Consumer into a generic class and it works. But is it possible to make the same Consumer class instance to work with multiple source types?

Comment: A class is either generic or not. It can't be both, you can't have a non-generic `Consumer` act like a generic `Consumer<T>`.  You only option is to have a non-generic base class with all the functionality _except_ the parts that require generic things.